# How to disable external links from YouTube

Tags: javascript, php, youtube

I want to make a Kindle Fire app for children that is a YouTube player. I am planning on writing it with PHP/HTML/JavaScript if possible. However, since it's for kids, I don't want the videos to be able to open external links, even when the ads are clicked. I don't have a problem with the ads themselves, just that when they are clicked they open in a browser window or something similar, and I don't want the kids to open random browser windows. Is it possible to stop this behavior? Would I need to write a custom player?

Comment: It'd be against YouTubes terms of service to get in the way of ads/stop them being clicked

Comment: If you can show me where it says that in the TOS, I'd really appreciate it. Thanks.

Comment: I've put my reply in an answer. It's also worth mentioning that YouTube already provide a service which is almost exactly as you suggest, ads in YouTube Kids are not clickable too (as per https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/6168681?hl=en)

Comment: Yeah. If it was available for Kindles, that would be awesome. It would be nice if that was something there was an option for in embedding things.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entry in the TOS where it prohibits what you wish to do:

> II. Prohibitions
>
> Your API Client will not, and You will not encourage or create functionality for Your users or other third parties to:
>
> 7. modify, replace, interfere with or block advertisements placed by
>    YouTube in the YouTube Data, YouTube audiovisual content, or the
>    YouTube player;

https://developers.google.com/youtube/terms

If you really want it ad-free, you could encourage parents to pay for YouTube Red to get YouTubes ad-free service, but I'm not sure how Red works with external players.